# How to merge duplicate rows of a dataframe containing np.nan in different columns to one row with just the not nan values?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, duplicates

I have a pandas dataframe which  has duplicate rows of the column symbol and looks like this:

```
df = 

| Index |  Symbol  | Column A | Column B |  Status  |
|-------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|   0   |    x     |     a    |  np.nan  |  Default |
|   1   |    y     |     d    |     c    |  Default |
|   2   |    x     |  np.nan  |     e    |  Default |
```

I want to have all the duplicate rows merged to unique rows, with the np.nan values in `Column A` and `Column B` replaced by values from the other duplicate rows, and the `Status` value of the row that was merged/changed to be set to Merged.
I want the output to look like this

```
| Index |  Symbol  | Column A | Column B |  Status  |
|-------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|   0   |    x     |     a    |     e    |  Merged  |
|   1   |    y     |     d    |     c    |  Default |
```

I have tried to separate the dataframes into duplicate and merge them again

`df1 = df.loc[df['Symbol'].duplicated()]`
then
`df = pd.concat([df, df1], join = 'inner', axis = 1)`

Other than this I have no idea how to proceed.

The accepted answer is not working on

````
|index|Ticker|Entry Date|Exit Date|Transaction Type|Entry Price|Exit Price|
|---         |---       |---|---|---|---|---|
|0|DEEPAKNTR |2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|386\.45|NaN|
|1|SRF       |2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|690\.53|NaN|
|2|RELAXO    |2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|629\.4|NaN|
|3|BERGEPAINT|2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|509\.8|NaN|
|4|ADANITRANS|2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|346\.55|NaN|
|5|ALKYLAMINE|2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|465\.24|NaN|
|6|ABBOTINDIA|2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|13248\.25|NaN|
|7|PHOENIXLTD|2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|857\.0|NaN|
|8|BAJFINANCE|2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|4193\.4502|NaN|
|9|MUTHOOTFIN|2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|770\.8|NaN|
|10|COFORGE  |2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|1630\.95|NaN|
|11|AAVAS    |2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|2039\.9|NaN|
|12|KOTAKBANK|2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|1657\.1|NaN|
|13|ADANIGREEN|2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|192\.6|NaN|
|14|RATNAMANI|2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|736\.0334|NaN|
|15|BAJAJFINSV|2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|934\.585|NaN|
|16|HCLTECH   |2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|585\.05|NaN|
|17|GMMPFAUDLR|2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|621\.9833|NaN|
|18|JUBLFOOD  |2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|336\.55|NaN|
|19|HDFC      |2020-01-03|NaN|Buy|2454\.45|NaN|```
````

The output shows `Gaps in blk ref_locs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `group by` symbol and use `bfill` to replace the missing values. Check if the group contains NaN's and change the status to `Merged`. Finally, return the first row of the group.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Symbol': ['x', 'y', 'x'],
    'Column A': ['a', 'd', np.nan],
    'Column B': [np.nan, 'c', 'e'],
    'Status': ['Default', 'Default', 'Default']
})

def merge_duplicates(group):
    if group.isna().sum(axis=1).sum() > 0:
        group.loc[group.index[0], 'Status'] = 'Merged'
    group = group.fillna(method='bfill')
    return group.iloc[0]


merged_df = df.groupby('Symbol').apply(merge_duplicates)
merged_df = merged_df.reset_index(drop=True)

merged_df
```

Output:

|  | Symbol | Column A | Column B | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | x | a | e | Merged |
| 1 | y | d | c | Default |

Comment: Thanks a lot. There's just one problem, The row containing ` 'y' ` wasn't merged but it's still changed to ` 'Merged' `

Comment: I've update the answer with a fix

Comment: Thank you so much, could you please help me understand or give some hints on how this works?

Comment: What the fix does is check if the group contains NaN's, if True changes the value of the `Status` column. The `bfill`method replaces the NaN's using the value of the next row going up, meaning the values are filled from the bottom to the top. Basically, you're replacing the missing values with the next known non-missing value.

Comment: I tried the code on this dataframe

Comment: I tried the code on this dataframe. I have edited the question to include it, the output says : Gaps in blk ref_locs

Comment: what's exactly the code you're running? I don't see how your question applies to that dataframe. You don't have duplicates Tickers or values useful to fill the NaN's. If that df it's not the input please upload your input dataframe, and add more information about what you're trying to do. So far this error it's not related to the original question.

Comment: This is one of the many dataframes on which I need to apply the above functionality, this dataframe in particular has no duiplicates, but some othe one might and in that case the rows will have np.nan in either ` 'Entry Price'  ` or  ` 'Exit Price' `

Comment: The code I have used is:

Comment: ```
def merge_duplicates(group):

    if group.isna().sum(axis=1).sum() > 0:

        group.loc[group.index[0], 'Status'] = 'Merged'

    group = group.fillna(method='bfill')

    return group.iloc[0]


merged_df = df.groupby('Ticker').apply(merge_duplicates)
merged_df = merged_df.reset_index(drop=True)

print(merged_df)
```